# How to tell if a remote copy of a working file was changed with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, tortoisesvn

When using ToroiseSVN, one may update his local copy of a repo with changes made by other parties and checked in to the remote repo.

If a remote file was changed while a local copy was in work, then updating the directory will not overwrite the local copy with the remote one (as it should be). However, TotoiseSVN's Update window does not indicate that there is a conflict.

Is there a way to get an indication for such conflict at the time of update?

Note: the Windows Explorer view shows the file as changed, so this is some sort of an indication, but if there are multiple files in multiple directories across the repo, I'd like to get a list of such at update time.

Comment: But you DO get an indication at time of update. SVN will automatically merge any changes it can figure out without user intervention and tell you the file was merged (with a G status if you're using the command-line, or "Merged" using TortoiseSVN). If SVN could not do the merge automatically, then it will show a "conflicted" status or even bring up a dialog for you to do the merge manually. Anything else is not a conflict, it's a merge or an update.

Comment: @Ben - Mmm... donno... last time I updated my repository, I had a source file which I put as a placeholder (contained just a `#warning` with a build-time message). At this time, another programmer checked in the actual working module. When I updated, I got no indication. As I mentioned, the status of the file (and containing directory hierarchy) showed the "changed" icon, so it is possible to track down such updates.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour may be specific to TortoiseSVN.

The following Command Prompt session uses the command line SVN client to match your scenario. In the session, I do the following:

- Checkout two working copies of the same repository.
- Create a file named blocker.txt in the first working copy.
- Create another file named blocker.txt in the second working copy.
- Add and commit to the repository only the blocker.txt in the second working copy. DON'T add the blocker.txt from the first working copy.
- Update the first working copy.

### Command Prompt session

```
C:\>svn --version   | findstr /c:"svn, version"
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)

C:\>svnadmin create C:\Temp\svn-test-repos

C:\>svn co file:///c:/Temp/svn-test-repos C:\Temp\wc1
Checked out revision 0.

C:\>svn co file:///c:/Temp/svn-test-repos C:\Temp\wc2
Checked out revision 0.

C:\>echo My first file  1>C:\Temp\wc1\blocker.txt

C:\>echo My second file  1>C:\Temp\wc2\blocker.txt

C:\>svn add C:\Temp\wc2\blocker.txt
A         Temp\wc2\blocker.txt

C:\>svn commit --message "blocker.txt added" C:\Temp\wc2
Adding         Temp\wc2\blocker.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 1.
```

The update of the first working copy results in the following error:

```
C:\>svn update --non-interactive C:\Temp\wc1
Updating 'Temp\wc1':
   C Temp\wc1\blocker.txt
At revision 1.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1

C:\>svn stat C:\Temp\wc1
D     C C:\Temp\wc1\blocker.txt
      >   local unversioned, incoming add upon update
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

Whereas TortoiseSVN updates the unversioned file without a conflict, the command line client has a conflict.

I don't know if you can use TortoiseSVN to get the behaviour you want. You may have to use the command line tool.

Comment: Thanks. I am not an SVN nor TortioseSVN expert, but I am convinced that if the SVN engine itself supports that, then there must be something wrong I did with the GUI client.